# Exporting Delorme Street Atlas draw files into KML

Tags: kml, export

(Using Delorme Street Atlas Plus USA 2015)

Is it possible to export a draw file into a KML file?  How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I wrote [a script](http://www.github.com/alex0112/mappy) that will translate draw files into KML.  It's far from complete but can do the basics. Requires some knowledge of the command line and a Perl interpreter.

---

I contacted support.  This is what they told me:

> Thank you for contacting DeLorme. I apologize but Street Atlas USA
>   does not have any export to KML capabilities. You can export waypoints
>   and tracks to GPX but not KML.

So that's that I suppose.  I may attempt to turn it into a GPX and then into a KML with some online program or something.  We'll see.